# displaying page with value with error message in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi guys I make my code simplier just to display the error message but still now showing.

```
 public function check_profile_ifexist($id)
  {

    if($this->input->post('edit')){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|valid_email|is_unique[user_details.email]'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|is_unique[user_details.username]|xss_clean');                $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique',"That %s already exists!");
    $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'the maximum characters for %s is 20');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'the minimum characters for %s is 6');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $this->load->model('model_user_manage');
        $em=$this->model_user_manage->update_all($id);
    }
    else
    {

     $this->view_profile($id);  
     }

}
```

}

Comment: hello sheikh can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing out all of your errors just store them all to a property:

First initiate an empty property so you know it exists - you could do this at the beginning of check_profile_ifexist() method:

```
 $this->profile_errors = '';
```

Then within your check_profile_ifexist() method just add the errors to the property as you go rather than echoing them e.g.

```
if (MD5($username)==$pass){
    echo "username cannot be the same as password";
}
```

becomes:

```
if (MD5($username)==$pass){
     $this->profile_errors .= "username cannot be the same as password\n";
}
```

This property will then be available to all your methods so you could add it to your data array in view_profile() like so:

```
if(isset($this->profile_errors)){
    $data['errors'] = $this->profile_errors;
}else{
    $data['errors'] = ''; 
}
```

and the errors are available in your view as $errors, so you could `echo $errors;` to print out all of the errors.

**NOTE** Obviously you will have to make sure that the property always exists or check for its existence to avoid errors of your own. I have also added newlines to your errors so that they will look a bit neater when printed out in bulk if more than one.

**SECOND NOTE** You seem to have a lot of stuff I would put in a model in this code, which I presume is a controller. You should probably keep all your db stuff in models or the MVC police will come for you.

Comment: hi webweaver thanks much for your idea, but can you suggest a good approach because even i am so confused on my codes though it works its kind a hard to read. I am doing an update profile where in user cannot update the username if its input is the same with the password and old username and also gives error message within the view that has a values on the textboxes

Comment: can you discuss more on the property where will i put this sorry I'm new to codeiginiter

Comment: A property is like a variable that is available to all the methods in your class. You could just declare the empty property at the beginning of your check_profile_ifexist() method. This will work fine if you dont call view_profile directly. Regardless, it would be good practice to check if it isset before using it. I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Hello Webweaver i tried your codes but there's error, i simplified the code can you help me on this.

Comment: I think you made it a bit too simple now. Whats the error you're getting and when is it happening. How are you passing the errors back to the view. Might be worth posting controller, model and view to get a complete picture of what is happening

Comment: I got it now now thanks much Webweaver I include if(isset($this->profile_errors)){
    $data['errors'] = $this->profile_errors;
}else{
    $data['errors'] = ''; 
}

Comment: Yes, that's probably a bit cleaner than declaring it elsewhere as I suggested. Glad you got it sorted. Dont forget to accept answers when your questions are resolved (tick next to answer)